# Resizing and positioning Excel windows correctly on a specific monitor

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

On opening `Excel` I want to programmatically create a new window of the workbook, similar to the `View Menu -> New Window` command in Excel.

Then I want to position and resize these windows to `60%` and `40%` of the screen resolution respectively and and they should be arranged side by side on a horizontal monitor in a dual monitor system.
The other monitor could either be vertical or horizontal.

All this works well when the horizonal monitor is the primary monitor but if its the secondary monitor.
The first window is not resized properly by width. and so there is an unused area left at the right end of the monitor as shown in the picture.

[image]

The resize code that I use is as under

```
    Sub Resize()
        Dim mainWindow As Window
    Dim secondWindow As Window

    'Recalculate new widths and positions
    Dim mainWindowWidth As Double
    Dim secondWindowWidth As Double

mainWindowWidth = 0.6 * screenWidthPoints
secondWindowWidth = 0.4 * screenWidthPoints

'Assign window variables
If Not IsNull(ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1)) Then
    Set mainWindow = ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1)

    'switch to normal state before setting width, else will throw error if the window state is maximized and then try to set width
    mainWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
    mainWindow.Left = horzMonPoints.Left
    mainWindow.Top = horzMonPoints.Top
    mainWindow.Width = mainWindowWidth
End If

If Not IsNull(ActiveWorkbook.Windows(2)) Then
    Set secondWindow = ActiveWorkbook.Windows(2)
    secondWindow.Top = mainWindow.Top
    secondWindow.Width = secondWindowWidth
    secondWindow.Left = mainWindow.Left + mainWindow.Width
    secondWindow.Height = mainWindow.Height
End If End Sub
```

The code to calculate number of monitors and monitor widths and heights, I used windows API calls in VBA.
From [this](https://www.developerfusion.com/thread/49351/vb-dual-screen/) link.

Comment: Where are you getting the size of the second screen? Is it being reported correctly?

Comment: @SolarMike  I'm getting the size of all the monitors using windows Api calls, its from the link that I've posted above. When I do a `MsgBox` the resoultion is reported correctly as 1920 x 1080. And btw I want to position and resize both windwows on the same horizontal screen.

Comment: So, if, as you state, those values are correct, then your calculations must be in error or the new values not being used correctly...

Comment: @SolarMike I tried debugging the code and at the point when I set the mainWindow.width I find that the value being set is reported incorrectly in mainWindow.width. The mainWindow.width shows a lower value than what I have set it to be. Which is kind of wierd.

Comment: points are not pixels 1920X1080 Pixels is approximate 1440 x 810 points. Is this your problem?

Comment: @HarassedDad I have another api call that checks the screen dpi, and calculates points per pixels which comes to 0.6 for my sysem. And as stated the code works on the primary monitory but fails on another system that as a secondary monitor as a horizontal screen.